# CSS-only way to ensure inline-block element is at least as wide as it is tall

Tags: html, css

I have a series of HTML elements with `display: inline-block`. They look like boxes. Here's a simplified example:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid darkblue 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">This<br>is<br>a<br>box</div>
<div class="box">This<br>is<br>a<br>tall<br>box</div>
<div class="box">This box is wider than it is tall<br>and therefore needs no adjustment</div>
```

What I need is for **each box to be at least as wide as it is tall**, subject to the following constraints:

- CSS only. No JavaScript
- The height and width of the boxes cannot be set explicitly (including min and max)
- `inline-block` behaviour is essential. A long line of boxes will need to wrap nicely, automatically
- Content within each box should be centre-aligned

I have found [a technique](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/) that will make an element at least as tall as it is wide but that relies on the fact that a percentage length for `margin` or `padding` is relative to the width of the element. There seems to be no equivalent for making a box at least as wide as it is tall.

Is it possible?

Comment: so it will be a square depending on the height it covers with the text?

Comment: A boxes that is naturally taller than it is wide due to its content will become a square, yes.

Comment: Can we use wrapper div + some css or just using inline-block and math you need the answer?

Comment: I'm open to changing the HTML but the `inline-block` behaviour is essential.

Comment: `Flexbox` is an option?

Comment: So you mean that `width` and `height`can't be used right? even with max and min?

Comment: Flexbox is definitely an option. Setting explicit width and height (even max and min) on the boxes themselves is out.

Comment: i dont think its possible with css only to get a square shaped element. With flexbox appraoch we can attain same height for all boxes .. but same width its not possible.. you need jquery to do this. As there are a lot of constraints in your question

Comment: I suspect you're right, Sahil, but I felt it was worth asking the question.

Comment: @TimDown your question is very interesting... may be in future there might be a way using css we can actually calculate width based on height ..  or I think with css preprocessor it might be possible

Comment: @SahilDhir You can't get the rendered value with preprocessors. However, what I've learned on Stack Overflow is that whenever someone says *it's not possible* the next moment someone else posts a creative solution. So don't give up hope yet ;)

Comment: @Marvin yes I too want to see someone answer this question . :)

Comment: This example seems to show the behavior you requested, but only in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/bxun6cc7/. I haven't yet figured out which browser gets the spec right here, but maybe this helps someone else to find the cross-browser solution?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn: Oh, that's promising. I'll have a play with that. Thank you.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn nice idea. The spec on this is confusing as hell, but my guess is that the relevant part is the desc. on the sizing phase in orthogonal flows, the [claculation in shrink-to-fit-scenarios](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#orthogonal-shrink-to-fit) and the following subsection on available space. I noticed that when toggling the padding on the after-element in the FF dev tools, the boxes size gets calculated correctly. Reproducable by applying the padding afterwards with JS: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxun6cc7/3/). Inspecting the element already reverts it.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious what the use case is that requires this... however I was immediately reminded of an article which covers several techniques that seem like they achieve what you want. The article goes deep into the `padding-top` trick to create containers that will maintain an "aspect ratio" so to speak.

Conceptually, this is the "trick":

```
padding-top: height / width * 100%;
```

Because `padding-top` (and `padding-bottom`) assigned to percentage values actually base the measurement of the values on the width of the element, you end up with a reliable aspect ratio div that scales.

Here is the link: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. By all means link to the source, but summarize the article in a way that directly answers the question.

Comment: Gotcha! Updated.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.box{
  display: inline-block;
 border: solid darkblue 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; 
}

.box-content{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-content"> Quae eveniet</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-content">Lorem ipsum, consectetur adipisicing elit.  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-content">facilis quos in repellendus rerum sequi. Magnam dolores commodi rem nemo, aliquam!</div>
</div>
```

If you want the content to start from the top instead of being vertically centered then change the `.box-content` padding to `padding-bottom: 100%`